# Retriving split data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Database layout]

```
         // how I get the data 
        db.collection('Pins').get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(pinInfo => {
             pinsToMap(pinInfo)
        });
    });

        // trying to set the data

     function pinsToMap(pinInfo){

    let pinName;
    let pinCoOrdsLat;
    let pinCoOrdsLong;
    let pinToMapInfo;

    pinName = doc.data().name
    pinCoOrds = doc.data().coOrds
    pinToMapInfo = doc.data().Info

    Pins.child(Pins.coOrds).set({
        coOrds: {
          0:this = pinCoOrdsLat,
          1:this = pinCoOrdsLong,
        }
    });
 }
```

I am storing data in my database based off a map pin, I am now trying to use the stored data to create a pin on the map of the same place, how do I query out the coOrds in to pinCoOrdsLat / pinCoOrdsLong as this way doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Where do you want to set the data? What are you trying to do with `Pins.child(Pins.coOrds).set()`? Writing to a Firestore collection? Calling a set() method of  a mapping library?

Comment: I want to set in pinCoOrdsLat / pinCoOrdsLong as I'm using leaflet.js and want be able to create markers using the points such as L.marker([pinCoOrdsLat, pinCoOrdsLong]).addTo(map);

Comment: And `pinCoOrdsLat` and `pinCoOrdsLong` come from the Firestore database, is that right?

Comment: no, they are just variables I have declared to assign the lat/ long to , in the Firestore database it is just set as coOrds, which I need to split I think due to it requiring two parameters to set a lat / long for the marker in leaflet, I'm unsure if there is a more efficient way / cleaner way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand you question, the following should do the trick:

```
db.collection('Pins').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(pinInfo => {
         pinsToMap(pinInfo)
    });
});

    // trying to set the data

function pinsToMap(pinInfo) {  // IMPORTANT! => pinInfo is a DocumentSnapshot

   const pinName = pinInfo.data().name
   const pinCoOrds = pinInfo.data().coOrds
   const pinToMapInfo = pinInfo.data().Info

   //pinCoOrds is a JavaScript Array with two elements

   const pinCoOrdsLat = pinCoOrds[0];
   const pinCoOrdsLong = pinCoOrds[1];


   //Use pinCoOrdsLat and pinCoOrdsLong the way you want, e.g. calling a leaflet method

}
```

---

You'll find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) the doc for a DocumentSnapshot